# Invocation of toString on an array - FindBugs

Tags: arrays, tostring, findbugs

I am getting the below Findbugs error for my code,

```
Invocation of toString on <<Package Path>>

 The code invokes toString on an array, which will generate a fairly useless
 result such as [C@16f0472. Consider using Arrays.toString to convert the
 array into a readable String that gives the contents of the array.
 See Programming Puzzlers, chapter 3, puzzle 12.
```

**Code:**

```
logger.info("Adding information"+ Employee.getName()+ " "+
            employeeForm.getQuestionAndAnswers());
```

Please let me know what is the error.

Comment: Please tell me where the error exactly in my code

Answer (score 24):

As it says, doing

```
myArray.toString()
```

will generate something useless like java.lang.int[]@45345262

you'd want to use

```
Arrays.toString(myArray);
```

Comment: Excellent Sir. Thumbs up! Printing the "hashcode" of an object is only useful to differentiate instances of the same type. Other than that, I consider it a Sin!